# Why is the scroll not working properly in the mobile version?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollview

I'm building this website with cargo collective and I'm having problems with the scroll of some pages, especially this one:

https://civitonia.cargo.site/26993899

After speaking with them they told me that is a problem related to the css and that they cannot put their hands on it. I can't figure out what's the problem about the scroll.

Does anyone knows what's the problem behind it?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your browser, i use chrome and firefox in mobile mode scroll is working , and i'm try in my handphone scroll is wornking,my phone POCO X3 PRO